# The prospective colleague who is trying to undervalue me

Tags: work-environment, colleagues

I am going to start on my very first real job soon. I have been an intern here for 6 months, and now will become a permanent employee. The team mostly consists of senior engineers and this colleague who has approximately 2 years experience.

This guy is trying to undervalue my work and my relationships with other team members. For example, I wrote a script that made everyone's job much easier, but he told everyone that I probably got the script from somewhere else. He said this with some humor, but he actually means it.

I promised myself that I won't do anything wrong in the business life and be a very straight person; no gossip, no wrong doing, always ethical etc. But, I am also starting to feel that I want to show this guy who I am, and I should be giving a lesson to him by the tactics he is trying to use. I can crush him like a bug by starting conversations about him with the other co-workers and give them the courage to talk about his personality, but I am not sure that I should, since this might cost him his job, and I would have to spend some time doing this, which would be hindering my job performance for a time.

Have anybody felt the same things before? If so, how did you tackle this situation?

Comment: Don't do anything that is going to hinder your own job performance. But I really have to know, how exactly can you "crush him like a bug"? And what are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Think a person nobody likes so much, but I have been nevertheless always been respectful. I can just start some conversations about him with the others and give the courage others to talk about his personality. I can also do the things better than him (some part of his responsibilities) in a shorter time and show people that he is easily irreplaceable.

Comment: How much time were you an intern before being a permanent employee?

Comment: For six months.

Comment: @matlabcrz, ok, and what do you get out of it? What goal are you trying to reach?

Comment: I edited your question and added that important detail and other minor edits.

Comment: There isn't much easier than doing the "right" thing when there isn't a clear short-term benefit to doing the "wrong" thing. If you're already thinking about doing questionable things, one has to wonder about your commitment to doing the right thing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly he's doing? At the moment this question seems too vague and broad to be properly answerable. You also might want to get rid of the whole "should I teach this guy a lesson"-type phrasing and instead just ask for advice on how to handle it.

Comment: You say "I can give others the courage to talk about him personally", I hear "I could make the workplace incredibly toxic". If you pull a stunt like that, you're not going to be working there for long.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I have been always known by the people as a very respectful person. But I also have some problems when somebody tries to challenge me with the false statements. Overall, from your comments, I deduce that I should be waiting for more and focus on my job only, since nobody here is telling me to counter act.

Comment: No-one's saying "do nothing" (or at least I'm not), but without some concrete examples of problematic behaviour from his side we can address, there isn't much advice to give other than "don't do anything shady".

Comment: @Dukeling I created some scripts that make easier everyone's job. He always, says to everybody that I possibly got the script from someone else. He says this with some humor, but he actually means it.

Comment: Edited the question to include some context provided here in the comments.

Comment: Yes just behave humbly, keep performing, keep your cool and don't show that you think his opinion holds any weight or that it even irritates you.

Comment: Keep doing good work even if he is berating you.  Eventually your other coworkers will see a pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Listen carefully -- just my opinion.  If he is actually spending time and energy to undermine you, either he:

1) He feels threatened by what he *perceives* to be your potential for accomplishment, as compared to his own, **-AND/OR-**

2) He's the kind of character that tries to elevate his own image in the eyes of others, by scoring points or demeaning someone in a softer position (i.e, "the new guy").  This is especially true if he seeks to devalue you in the eyes of others (whether in your presence or behind your back).

I know you're angry at this guy, and for the incredible hubris he's showing in demeaning you (you're going to meet lots of people like this in life).

My opinion?  Do not engage him in any sort of conflict.  In fact, don't even be impolite to him (from now on).  Do a good job, and the team will come to rely on you.  Focus on your work and make it solid.  If he ever tries to demean your **work** in front of others, then calmly say "I have a different take on it -- give me a minute to show you" -- and *explain to the whole group* in a calm and polite way your (hopefully correct) method that he was trying to unjustly demean.  Stick to your guns when you know you're right -- people will come to respect you for it.

Again, do not get into a conflict with him.  People like this can be like cornered animals.  There is a risk that, if he feels threatened by you, he'll pull out every vicious trick in the book, because in reality he's actually insecure.  No doubt you can fight back, but do you want to go to work into a war zone every day, not knowing what the latest trap he's set for you is?

Focus on your work, and work quality.  When you do this, eventually -- when he's trying to put you down sometime, one of the person's on his team that he respects/fears is going to say to him "Come on, let's lay off ____,  man.  He works hard and does a good job."

After that, HE WILL STOP, because his behaviour will have started to hurt **his** image in the eyes of others.  **People get tired of people who bring negative energy.  Be a source of positive energy in your workplace, and people will love working with you.**  Then, the sky's the limit for your success.  Take the high road and you will never be sorry.  And if in the end it turns out that you're just plain working with a bunch of jerks, then maybe you don't really need to be there anyway, right?

Just show your value through your work.  Keep your integrity -- don't sell it away to try to survive.  As an older guy I can tell you -- it is what will matter MOST to you in the end.

P.S.  No, you don't need to do anything to reduce his envy of you.  Don't add extra "duties" like that to your work responsibilities, you have enough on your plate :)

That being said, there's actually nothing wrong with eventually making friends with the guy, after he gets over his problem with you -- **but he must respect you first**, or else he'll think you're being friendly or trying to put him at ease out of fear (and that you're now his "lackey").

**Behave humbly (meaning not pridefully) but never genuflect.**

Definitely don't do or say anything to make him look bad (damage his "face").  It would likely "trigger" increased negative behavior from him.  If you've done something to make him "lose face", then find out something he likes (like coffee for instance), then get him a bag of specialty coffee or something and say "I found this great tasting coffee.  I know you like a good brew, so I wanted to see what you thought about it".  That kind of thing.  **But only do this if you've caused him to lose face at some point.**  **Don't give him the gift in front of others.**  Do it privately, and it will privately make peace between you -- if the offense given wasn't horribly egregious.

Comment: I agree with most of this, but it's worth adding that you need experience to really know if you're right or wrong. I actually find much more respect for people who, when they realize they made a mistake, own up to it and learn from it, as opposed to people who constantly think they're always right.

Answer (score 9):

Don't take this personally, but situations like this almost always have at least 2 sides to them.

Often times what you perceive to be him undervaluing your work might be constructive criticism, albeit probably delivered in a less than tactful manner. The example you provided (of writing a script that made everyone's lives easier) could actually also be taken as a compliment, as they may not have expected you to provide a script of such quality and joked that you got it from elsewhere.

---

> I can crush him like a bug

This statement worries me, as it sounds vastly overconfident in something that cannot possibly be constructive or productive. Chest-thumping and machismo don't go very far in a professional setting.

It sounds like you need to rein it in a bit, and possibly talk to another colleague about your job performance. Clearly they felt that you did a good enough job as an intern to be hired full-time; there's no need to have to exert your dominance over someone that admittedly has more experience than you do (even if only by 2 years).

Overall, just stick to doing your job, and if you feel worried about your job performance, bring it up with your supervisor. Learning and growing your experience will take you a lot further than simply trying to best your co-workers.

Answer (score 3):

From what you describe, it doesn't sound like this guy is your manager, so what difference does it make if he undervalues your work? He isn't responsible for evaluating you. If you are looking to get ahead, you only need to impress your employer.

If you feel like you need to prove you are better than him for whatever reason, fine. Go prove it. Be the best employee you can be. Show them and him what you can do. You don't need to destroy his career to do it. In fact, any attempt to do that is far more likely to destroy your career than his.

Don't start your career this way. Just focus on your job.

Answer (score 2):

> I can crush him like a bug

This under no circumstance can ever be OK, as you will be actively working to damage someone's reputation something that may not be ethic at all. Also, if doing that will mean **less time doing your work** (as you mentioned) then that is another reason not to do it.

I believe that your coworker is behaving like that because he/she is feeling **envy**; you were an intern, did a great job, and now they want you in permanent position. Your coworker may feel threatened by your capabilities. This is clearly due to some **personality issues** your coworker has, and only he/she can work to overcome that state of mind. Taking it personal on him/her will only worsen this situation.

In any case, if this situation continues you should **speak to your manager** or someone in charge about it. Always remember to be clear and straightforward; doing things without the knowledge of your coworkers is also something not recommended.

Comment: About the envy; could I do anything to diminish his envy, while not being seen as weak?

Comment: I believe that is a personal problem your coworker has. If he is envious it is because he has issues accepting that others may be better than him. In any case you should not actively try to make him feel less envious, as he is behaving that way because of your skills (or do you plan to be less skillful to make him feel better?). However, also refrain from bragging out your capabilities. I am going to edit my answer and add these details.

Answer (score 0):

Leave it to your boss to value your work.  Drama at work is stupid and pointless.  Just remember that he/she is your peer.  try to learn everything you can from everyone, and remember the parts that are valuable.

Also remember what it feels like in this situation, so you never accidentally do this to someone else in 10 years :)